# How to run all features for different locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am developing an automation suite for e-commerce website which has site pages for different countries. I have developed all most 100's of test cases for various functionalities of the site. Now, my requirement is to test the same functionalities for all the different countries (locales.)

For example,

```
Locale  QA                  Production  

    US  XXXqa.com       XXX.com                 
    UK  uk-XXXqa.com    XXX.co.uk                   
    FR  fr-XXXqa.com    XXX.fr                  
    AU  au-XXXqa.com    XXX.com.au                  
    DE  de-XXXqa.com    XXX.de                  
    CA  ca-XXXqa.com    XXX.ca                  
    JP  jp-XXXqa.com    XXX.co.jp                   
    CN  cn-XXXqa.com    XXX.cn
```

For login tests, I am writing this modification to include all countries

```
     Scenario Outline: Existing user can sign in
            Given I am an existing user
            And I go to the <Country> homepage
            And I click the 'LOG IN' link
            And I am presented with the Log In modal
            When I enter my credentials and click the LOG IN button 
            Then I am logged in
    Examples:
            | country  |
            | US |
            | AU  |
            | FR |


Given /^I go to the (\w+) homepage$/ do |country|
  @country = country_url
end
```

It seems working for the test as it is able to navigate to different countries & test the functionality. However, I will have to modify more than 1000 lines of code if I follow this approach. Is there any other alternative to navigate through each country & test the login functionality?

Comment: why don't you create an array with the country codes and then, in your test, when you have to visit the homepage, you can do a for loop from the first country 'till the last one and `visit("#{country-code}-XXXqa.com")`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get one run of cucumber to deal with all of your locales I would run cucumber once for each of your locales.

You can restrict which scenarios you run when doing this using tags e.g.

@locale
Scenario: Existing user can log in

What you'll probably have to do is something clever to configure the host_name so that when you do `visit login_path` it evaluates to the correct route. This can probably be done using an Environment variable and some clever stuff with configuration. What you are looking to do is change `Capybara.default_host` for each particular run.

Once this is working, I'd use a CI server to actually manage running cucumber multiple times.

Hope thats enough to get you started :)